# Ruby on Rails group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, relational-database

I am using PostgreSQL in my Rails Application and have the following model

```
Log(id: integer, session: string, user: string, application: string, activity: string, event: string, time: datetime, parameters: hstore, extras: hstore, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Now, I would like to get the count of event for each user. I type the following in Rails console

```
 Log.select("count(event) as event_count").group("user")
```

But , I get

```
Log Load (0.7ms)  SELECT count(event) as event_count FROM "logs"  GROUP BY user
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Log id: nil>]>
```

Am I doing something terribly wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a statistics for every user use [group](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-group) and [count](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count) like this:

```
Log.group('"user"').count(:event)
```

This will return a hash having your user as a key and the value is the count value like this:

```
{name1: 2, name2: 12, ... }
```

The query sent to the database:

```
SELECT COUNT("logs"."event") AS count_event, "user" AS user FROM "logs"  GROUP BY "user"
```

I double escaped `user` column to let Postgres use the column named user from logs table and not the user function defined into Postgres.

---

The way you're doing it is not wrong, but is more verbose.
To see the result when you do

```
Log.select("count(event) as event_count").group("user")
```

do like this:

```
Log.select('"user", count(event) as event_count').group('"user"').all.each do |stats|        
  puts "#{stats.user} => #{stats.event_count}"
end
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me! The query sent is `SELECT COUNT("logs"."event") AS count_event, user AS user FROM "logs"  GROUP BY user` and I get  `{"log_manager"=>94}` as result. On the other hand ` SELECT DISTINCT "logs"."user" FROM "logs"` gives `[nil, "apeeyush", "peeyush", "Peeyush", ""] `

Comment: I had a similar problem, and I don't know way the database uses the user you use to log in. If you can, rename user to username in your logs table  and do the test again.

Comment: The user is not used for logging in. It is just a Log Data table which has a column called user. I don't think renaming it will have any effect. Should I still try to rename it?

Comment: Just do the test with a different name instead of user for your column. I try to find a solution using user as a column name.

Comment: To make the query work use `Log.group('"user"').count(:event)`. (Observe the escaping of user column.) In this way Postgres will use your column named user and not the user function that exists in Postgres

Comment: It worked! Thanks very much.. I will accept your answer once you update it.

Comment: The second method of using `Log.select("count(event) as event_count").group("username").all.each do |stats|
  stats.event_count
end` does not seem to work still! I get `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Log id: nil>, #<Log id: nil>, #<Log id: nil>, #<Log id: nil>]> ` as query response.. Any idea of what may be wrong with this query?

Comment: I updated the answer to display the name for what you the that way

Comment: Thanks! I was not using puts earlier. I think it was because of Lazy Loading in Rails that it was not showing result when not using puts.